# Group by without using pandas

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, text, reduce

I have a csv file and the sample looks like,

```
year   product   country
2018    food       us
2018    drink      uk
2019    food       uk
2019    car      japan
2018    food     japan
```

Can I group the information by year without using packages like pandas or numpy?
I know we can first read the input by using standard package `csv`.

```
f = open('text.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
  ////////
```

My expected output is,

```
year   product    product_sum
2018    food         2
2018    drink        1
2019    food         1
2019    car          1
```

Comment: Yes, of course you can. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Are you looking for this specific case or a general solution?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm trying to use reduce function to solve this.

Comment: Hi @AmalTs I hope to get a general solution.

Comment: Why? That isn't really what reduce is for. But again, what have you tried out exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the number of occurrences.

```
f = open('text.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
next(csv_f, None)  # Ignore header row

c = collections.Counter((year, product) for year, product, country in csv_f)
print(c)
# Output: Counter({('2018', 'food'): 2, ('2018', 'drink'): 1, ('2019', 'food'): 1, ('2019', 'car'): 1})
```

To write it back to a CSV file, you can use `.items()` and list comprehension to turn it back into a flat list and write using `writerows`.

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
  writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
  writer.writerow(('year', 'product', 'product_sum'))
  writer.writerows([(key[0], key[1], value) for key, value in c.items()])
```

Note: For Python 2, use `iteritems()` instead of `items()`.

---

You can use `reduce` for this problem, but personally I don't find that very natural nor very Pythonic. But here's how it's done anyway.

```
def reduce_func(acc, update):
  year, product, country = update
  acc[(year, product)] += 1
  return acc

resultdict = reduce(reduce_func,
                    csv_f,
                    collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0))

print(resultdict)
# Output: defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x1007042f0>, {('2018', 'food'): 2, ('2018', 'drink'): 1, ('2019', 'food'): 1, ('2019', 'car'): 1})
```

If you don't want to / can't use `collections.Counter` for some reason I'd recommend to go with Amal TS' answer to build the dictionary in a loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this. Using a tree or simple dict.

This solution assumes that the fields in group by are adjacent. With little change you can generalize or explore the tree based approach for neat solution.

````py
f = open('text.csv')
delim = "\t"
header = f.readline()
group_dict = {}
for l in f.readlines():
      key = delim.join(l.split()[:2])
      if key not in group_dict:
            group_dict[key] = 0
      group_dict[key] +=1

f2 = open('output.txt','w')
f2.write(header)
for k,v in group_dict.items():
      f2.write(delim.join([k,str(v)])+'\n')```
````